# Modify contents of DIV in HTML using Perl+XPath

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, html

I have $html which contains HTML code. Somewhere in the HTML there is a DIV with the id "content". My goal is to replace the HTML contents of this DIV. I read on this website that it's best to use a parser when working with HTML, rather than regex.

What I did so far (using XPath which is ideal):

```
my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new();
$tree->parse_content($html);
$content = $tree->findnodes_as_string('//div[@id="content"]');
```

This gives me the entire HTML content of the DIV that i want to replace... but the question is how can I replace this content? I tried (but didn't work):

```
$html =~ s/$content/$newhtml/mgs;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from `findnodes_as_string` is just a string, it's no longer part of the `HTML::Element` object that holds the document. You need to update the object itself if you want to be able to output it.

You need to use `findnodes` to get the element (you get a list of matching elements, take the first one in that list), then you can replace its content using `replace_with`. You may need to pass an `HTML::Element` object to `replace_with`, if `$newhtml` contains markup (ie if it's not simple text content).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $html=q{<html><head><title>foo</title></head>
                 <body><div id="title">foo</div>
                       <div id="content"><p>1 para</p><p>2 para's</p></div>
                 </body>
          </html>};

my $new_content='<div id="content"><p>new para 1</p><p>new para 2</p></div>';

my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new();
$tree->parse_content($html);

# findnodes erturns a list of elements, take the first one
my $div = ($tree->findnodes('//div[@id="content"]'))[0];
# replace the div with an element created from $new_content
$div->replace_with( HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content( $new_content));

print $tree->as_HTML;
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) supports CSS selectors instead of XPath, which I find much simpler when manipulating HTML. This will replace the content of the `#content` element with `$newhtml` in `$html`:

```
use Mojo::DOM;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $html );
$dom->at( '#content' )->replace_content( $newhtml );
print $dom;
```

Comment: Also a good solution! Using CSS may be even better than XPath when working with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

may `$content` contain characters with special significance in regex patterns, namely from the set `*+?|[]{}^$` ?

you better escape metacharacters in the variable holding the pattern:

```
$html =~ s/\Q$content\E/$newhtml/mgs;
```

(see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#ESCAPE-SEQUENCES) for details).

Comment: Good idea, but i believe regex is probably not the best way to do this, because the problem is that the original $html contains different html entities than the content TreeBuilder gives me... one difference and it won't work with regex.

Comment: it depends on what you plan to do with the result. the suggested solution actually doesn't apply a regex but matches literally instead. the extraction, being the most critical part, employs xpath. as an element with a given `id` attribute is selected, the result string should be guaranteed to occur only once. new entities introduced by the replacement do not matter if the result doesn't need to be integrated into an existing parse tree (eg. being written to a file instead).